# List all hitTypes through the mturk API?

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

Is there a way to list all my HIT **types** (not HITs or assignments) using the mturk api?

I can't find any documentation on this. I'm using python, so it'd be nice if boto supported this query.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this? If you recreate a HITType with the exact same parameters as a previous one, MTurk will spit back the exact same HITTypeId, so there's no need to worry about duplication.

Comment: Yes: I want to provide continuity for turkers by publishing HITs in the same "batch."  Since posting this question, I've built a locally persistent DB of HITTypes, like Chris suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the MTurk API (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/Welcome.html) I don't see anything that returns a list of HIT types.  You should post a query to the MTurk forum (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=11).  It seems like a useful feature to add.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't. We resort to persisting every HitType locally that we create through turk's api at houdiniapi.com which works just fine.